# Assigning values to a lists

Tags: python-3.x

The statement  "a[i]=GEH" is not assigning the value of GEH to the list. 
Why is that? Much appreciated if someone can tell me what did I do wrong.

The code:-

```
import os, sys
global rec

def interpret_string(s):
    if not isinstance(s, str):
        return str(s)
    if s.isdigit():
        return int(s)
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

f= open("turn.prn","r")
f1=open('turn.out', 'a')

if f.mode == 'r':
    fl = f.readlines()

i = 0
a = [0.0] * 1000
rec = [0] * 1000

for x in fl:
    vol = interpret_string(x[90:96])
    ul1 = interpret_string(x[32:40])
    ul2 = interpret_string(x[41:49])

    if vol != str(x[90:96]):
        if vol > 0 and ul1 > 0:
            Diff = (((ul1 - vol) / ul1) ** 2) ** 0.5
            GEH  = (((2 * (ul1-vol)**2))/(ul1+vol))**0.5
            if GEH > 0.0 :
               a[i]=GEH
               rec[i] = i
               i=i+1
               print(i,a[i],rec[i],GEH)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Regards

Razif

Comment: How do you know it is not assigned? Which debugger have you been using to step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

If hav no posibility of testing it right now, but since you seem to want to have a List consisting of "None" values if the if is not matched and "GEH" if matched I'd use an "else" - Statement and append None as well.

```
import os, sys
global rec

def interpret_string(s):
    if not isinstance(s, str):
        return str(s)
    if s.isdigit():
        return int(s)
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

f= open("turn.prn","r")
f1=open('turn.out', 'a')

if f.mode == 'r':
    fl = f.readlines()

i = 0
a = [0.0] * 1000
rec = [0] * 1000

for x in fl:
    vol = interpret_string(x[90:96])
    ul1 = interpret_string(x[32:40])
    ul2 = interpret_string(x[41:49])

    if vol != str(x[90:96]):
        if vol > 0 and ul1 > 0:
            prin = false # This will trigger the print only if the if-
                         # condition is met
            Diff = (((ul1 - vol) / ul1) ** 2) ** 0.5
            GEH  = (((2 * (ul1-vol)**2))/(ul1+vol))**0.5
            if GEH > 0.0 :
               a.append(GEH)
               prin = true
            else :
               a.append(None)
            rec[i] = i
            i=i+1
            if prin :
                print(i,a[i],rec[i],GEH)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Sorry for the messy print "if" - it was the easiest way I could come up with ;).
As I said, I couldn't test, but I think this could work.